# Find the limit to the following

Tags: analysis

Please if any one can find the following limit:

Let $b$ be a real number, $b>1$. Compute
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\biggl(\frac1{b^n}+\frac1{b^{2n}}+\frac1{b^{3n}}
+\dots+\frac1{b^{(n-1)n}}+\frac1{b^{n^2}}\biggr).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's squeeze!
$$
0 \leq n\left(\frac{1}{b^n} + \dots + \frac{1}{b^{n^2}}\right) \leq n\times \frac{n}{b^n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$

*Edited according to Matt's comment.*

Comment: Well, that is mean that the limit is 0 right? but could you please tell how n\times \frac{n^2}{b^n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0

Comment: @Ju'x: shouldn't there be only $n^2$ on the right hand side of the inequality (instead of $n^3$)? There are only $n$ terms between the parentheses.

Comment: @user50382: check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial

Comment: @Matt: of course you're right, but I needed not be very sharp.