# At what point does exponential growth dominate polynomial growth?

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, computational-complexity

It's well-known that exponential growth eventually overtakes polynomial growth ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial), [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499446/is-every-exponential-grows-faster-than-every-polynomial-always-true)).

So for any non-negative integer $d$ and positive $\epsilon$, there exists $t^* \ge 0$ for which

$$
1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \ldots + \frac{t^d}{d!} \le e^{\epsilon t} 
$$

for all $t \ge t^*$.

In other words, it takes $t^*$ seconds for the exponential to catch up with the polynomial.

I'd like to know if there's a closed-form expression for $t^*$ in terms of $d$ and $\epsilon$. Something like

$$
t^* = d/\epsilon.
$$

Thoughts?

Comment: +1, if only for linking to other questions and thereby improving this site's coherence :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there is no such closed-form expression, but closed-form bounds are possible.

EDIT:
Of course if $\epsilon \ge 1$, the inequality is true for all $t \ge 0$, so 
consider the case $0 < \epsilon < 1$.  I'll denote the left side as $M_d(t)$.
We can consider this as $e^{t} \mathbb P[X \le d]$, where $X$ is a random variable having Poisson distribution with parameter $t$.
Now for any $\mu > 0$, 
$$\mathbb P[X \le d] =  \mathbb P\left[e^{-\mu X} \ge e^{-\mu d}\right] < e^{\mu d} \mathbb E\left[ e^{-\mu X}\right] =  e^{\mu d} e^{-t + t \exp(-\mu)} $$
Thus it suffices to have
$  \mu d + t \exp(-\mu) \le \epsilon t $, i.e. $\exp(-\mu) < \epsilon$ with 
$$ t  \ge \dfrac{\mu d}{\epsilon-\exp(-\mu)}$$
It's not quite optimal, but you could e.g. take
$\mu = -\ln(\epsilon/2)$, and then the bound is
$$  t \ge \dfrac{2 d \ln(2/\epsilon)}{\epsilon} $$

Comment: What sorts of bounds?

Comment: Thanks very much! This bound is tighter than @Gabriel's, (for $d=1$ and $\epsilon=0.1$, it's $t^*=180$ vs his $650,000$). The middle inequality comes from the [Markov Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) I assume. This is very interesting, I've never seen probability used to solve a non-probabilistic problem before.

Comment: Using probability to solve a non-probabilistic problem is not so uncommon.  [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9218/probabilistic-proofs-of-analytic-facts/9222) are some examples.

Comment: Thanks for the nice ref in your comment. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, and the pointer!

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to take $t^* = e(d+1)!/\epsilon^{d+1}$.

Proof:

The LHS of the desired inequality is at most $t^d/0! + t^d/1! + \cdots t^d/d! \le et^d$ (assuming $t\ge 1$ which is fine).

The RHS of the desired inequality is at least $(\epsilon t)^0/0! + \cdots + (\epsilon t)^{d+1}/(d+1)! \ge (\epsilon t)^{d+1}/(d+1)!$.

Therefore, it is enough if we ensure that $et^d \le (\epsilon t)^{d+1}/(d+1)!$. But this is equivalent to $t\ge e(d+1)!/\epsilon^{d+1}$.

With more effort one could presumably improve the dependence of $t^*$ on $d$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: Masterfully done! Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.