# Does an exponential decay faster than a polynomial, in the limit of an infinite power?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials, exponential-function

We know that
$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x}\, x^n = 0$$
for any $n$. But I assume that usually, this is stated with the understanding that $n$ is finite. But what happens when we take the limit
$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x}\, x^n = 0\,?$$
The context is that I have an infinite sum of the form
$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \mathrm{e}^{-x}\, x^i,$$ and I want to study its behavior as $x \rightarrow \infty$. In summary,

> Does
>   $$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x}\, x^i,$$
>   converge?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499446/is-every-exponential-grows-faster-than-every-polynomial-always-true) seems to indicate that the answer might be yes, but I wonder if taking $n \rightarrow \infty$ messes anything up?

Comment: Factor out by $e^{-x}$ and use geometric sum.

Comment: The double limit depends on how $n$ and $x$ tend to $\infty$. In particular, if $x=n$, the limit won't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is one of interchanging the order of limits.  Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n e^{-x}x^i&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(e^{-x}x^i\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^n (0)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Here, we first hold $n$ fixed and let $x\to\infty$.  The result of the inner limit is $0$ for any $n$.  Then, letting $n\to\infty$ produces $0$ as the result.

However, if the order of the limits is interchanged, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^n e^{-x}x^i&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-x}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

which diverges since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=\infty$ for $x>1$.  In this case, we first hold $x>1$ fixed and take the limit as $n\to\infty$. The resultant limit diverges and renders the outer limit as $x\to\infty$ meaningless.

---

Aside, we ask what is the limit, if it exists, of $e^{-x}x^x$ as $x\to\infty$?  We find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}x^x&=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x} e^{x\log(x)}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x\log(x/e)} \\\\
&=\infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: We have to consider $x\rightarrow \infty$ , so $|x|<1$ does not hold.

Comment: @Peter The limit does not exist for $|x|\ge 1$.

Comment: I just noticed that two different limits are mentioned.

Comment: @Peter I've edited the content to provide a hopefully clearer explanation.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Does this imply that if, hypothetically, we get convergence for both possibilities of the order in which limits are applied, then we can safely say that the double limit converges? For example, if I was now considering $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}h(x)\mathrm{e}^{-x}x^i$ such that I know that the sum converges for any finite x.

Comment: Not necessarily, but [The Moore-Osgood Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moore-Osgood_Theorem) provides sufficient conditions  when the limits can be interchanged.