# Polynomial upper bounding by $2^x$. True or false?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following proposition and I am not sure whether it is true or not.
Don't necessarily need a proof.

$$
\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: \text{ as }x\to\infty , a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n \le 2^x
$$
where $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_n$  are constants.

Basically, for any polynomial, does $2^x$ eventually pass it?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499446/is-every-exponential-grows-faster-than-every-polynomial-always-true)

Comment: You can also write this as $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots + a_n x^n \in O \left( 2^x \right)$.  It's known as Landau notation, or sometimes "Big Oh" notation.

Answer (score 0):

It is true, $2^x=e^{\ln {2^x}}=e^{x.\ln 2}$ and the exponential function is always greater than any polynomial as $x$ goes to positive infinity.

Comment: This feels a little like kicking the can down the road. It just moves the question to one in terms of $e^x$ instead and completely neglects that there is a proof for that too.

Comment: I'd like to see another proof for the question, but this is all what came into my head so far and I thought it would help, and also Colin doesn't really seem that he wants a proof for this one

Comment: $e^{x \ln2}\geq (x\ln2)^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ for positive $x$.