# How does $\ln(x)$ blow up at $0$ and $\infty$.

Tags: limits, logarithms, infinity

In general: How do I figure out how fast a function blows up at a certain point or infinity?

How fast does $\ln x$ blow up at $0$? Does it blow up as fast as $1/x$, $1/x^2$, or maybe faster than any $1/x^n$?

How do I answer such a question about other types of functions? How do I answer such a question for infinity?

I know that $\ln x$ blows up very slowly at infinity, slower than any $x^n, n>0$. How do I justify this information?

Edit: After some thinking I realized that lnx is e^x flipped about y=x. This means lnx is asymptotic to the -y axis as e^-x is asymptotic to +x axis. This is an intuitive justification of lnx blowing up slower than any x^-n, n>0

Comment: The easy way is just using l'Hospital's rule. Consider the ratio $\frac{\log x}{x^n}$ as $x\to+\infty$ or the product $x^n\log x$ as $x\downarrow 0$. You can evaluate those limits easily by the aforementioned rule of calculus.

Comment: Try looking at limits of ratios:  $\lim_{x \to \infty}   \frac{\ln x}{x^a}.$

Comment: I know how to answer this question for two particular functions. lnx vs 1/x was only an example/motivation. I want to know if there is a classification of how functions blow up.

Comment: Suppose $\lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)| = \lim_{x \to 0} |g(x)| = +\infty$. We say that $f$ "blows up" faster than $g$ if $\lim_{x \to 0}\bigg|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \bigg|= +\infty$.

Comment: $\log x = -\log (1/x)$ so if you know how fast $\log$ grows towards $x=\infty$ you automatically knows the behaviour at $x=0$.

Comment: Consider http://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468/160028 for explaining why exponential grow faster than polynomial