# Determine whether $x^3 > 2^{x/2}$

Tags: inequality

Determine whether there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^3 > 2^{x/2}$ for $x \in [c, \infty)$.

Comment: You do not "prove if something". You probably mean "Determine whether something." Said determination may naturally include a proof.

Comment: Well the inequality holds for $x=2$, but not for $x=1$. It does not hold for $x\geq 29.22$.

Comment: Changed the question from 'Prove that' to 'Determine whether'.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: there were some mistakes in the way you had written the question. I edited. Please read over the edits to understand the errors.

Comment: @par : Sorry for the errors. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: I suppose you could take logs of both sides, giving the question $3 \ln x \gt x \ln \sqrt{2}$? This looks like you need to determine $x$ st $\ln x > x \ln 2^{1/6}$ or $\ln x \gt 0.116 x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** there exists a $c$ such that for all $x \geq c$, $x^3 < 2^{x/2}$ (i.e. the function on the right grows faster than the function on the left). [See also this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bx%5E3,%202%5E(x%2F2)%7D,%7Bx,0,40%7D%5D).

**Hint 2:** [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial).

Comment: Can it be solved without plotting a graph? Through some other inequality or identity?

Comment: Yes, I was just providing you with a hint on how to proceed. Try to find a $c$ as described in my hint.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you should try plotting these graphs or trying various values of $x$ first. You'll find your answer pretty easily.