# Find $\lim _{x\to \infty }x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ without L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }x^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ How can I solve this? I want the most simple way to do it. Is there a nice log rule I can use here? I'm definitely not at the stage of using the limit chain rule as suggested on [SymboLab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%5Cright)).

I couldn't get anywhere with it using the methods I know ($0/0, a/0, a/\infty,$ basic logs).

**Edit:** This is an *extremely* snaky move from me to add the limits-without-lhopital tag now. Is it too late, or do I need to add a separate question?

Comment: See also: [Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[x]{x}=1$ (No L'Hôpital)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2105965)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ we have that $\;\log x<x^\epsilon\;$ for any $\;0<x\in\Bbb R\;$ big enough , you then don't need l'Hospital since we can write

$$\frac{\log x}x<\frac{x^\epsilon}x=\frac1{x^{1-\epsilon}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0\;,\;\;\text{for say}\;\;0<\epsilon<1$$

Using that $\;\log x>\log1=0\;$ for $\;x>1\;$, use the squeeze theorem to deduce that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}x=0$$

and, as in the other answers, use now the algebraic equality

$$x^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\log x}\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\log x}=e^0=1$$

Comment: nice answer,without l'hospital rule ,+1

Comment: What is an elementary way to show the first claim (that $\log x = O(x^\epsilon)$)?

Comment: @angryavian I'm not sure. I think I can  prove it by means of differentials but I'm not sure if this makes the cut of "elementary".

Comment: @DonAntonio I guess I meant (ideally) without calculus, or at at least something at the same level as the rest of your answer. Is there something along the lines of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/55488/43949)?

Answer (score 7):

firstly,write it as $x^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }={ e }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { x }  }$
now we have such limit $$\lim _{ x\to \infty  } e^{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ x }  }=\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ { e }^{ \frac { f\left( x \right) \rightarrow \infty  }{ g\left( x \right) \rightarrow \infty  }  } } ,\quad where\quad f\left( x \right) =\ln { x } ,g\left( x \right) =x $$ 
so we can apply L'hospital's rule

> $$\lim _{ x\to \infty  } x^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }=\lim _{ x\to \infty  } e^{ \frac { 1 }{ x } \ln { x }  }=\lim _{ x\to \infty  } e^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }=1$$

Comment: Can you do this step-by-step providing sources or explanations for the properties you have used?

Comment: @MaxLi The first two are algaebraically equal.  The second and third involve L'Hopital's Rule.  And the last is evaluating the limit.

Comment: Is there a way without L'Hôpital's Rule?

Comment: yes,you can prove that $x>\ln { x } ,x>1$ so that x "runs" to infinity more quickly than  $lnx$

Comment: Yes: the next answer, which uses only a basic limit from high school. L'Hospital's rule is *not* the alpha and omega of limits computation.

Comment: @Battani: proving $x>\ln x$ is not enough to prove $\dfrac{\ln x}x\to 0$ when $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Bernard Indeed so...but *almost* .

Answer (score 3):

$x^{1/x}=e^{\ln(x)/x}$ so the limit is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}e^{\ln(x)/x}$.
You know that $\lim\limits_{+\infty}\ln(x)/x=0$ this implies that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}e^{\ln(x)/x}=1.$

Comment: Can you do this step-by-step providing sources or explanations for the properties you have used?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $ln(x)$ not $log(x)$?

Comment: @MaxLi $\log = \ln$ for most purposes. Also, passing the limit to the exponent is justified by continuity of $\exp$.

Comment: @MaxLi Under the right context (computer science) $\log$ can imply $\log_2$.  Usually, $\log=\log_{10}$, and if we are doing limits/calculus, $\log=\log_e=\ln$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider this
for integer $n$,
you want to show that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n}
= 1
$.

Here's a bit of magic:

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^n
\ge 1+n\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
\ge 1+\sqrt{n}
\gt \sqrt{n}
= n^{1/2}
$.

Raising both sides
to the $2/n$ power,
$((1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^n)^{2/n}
> (n^{1/2})^{2/n}
$
or
$(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^2
> n^{1/n}
$
or
$n^{1/n}
< (1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^2
=1+2\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{n}
<1+3\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
$.

Since
$n^{1/n} > 1$
and
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
=0
$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n} 
=
1
$.

Answer (score 0):

As to avoiding the use of L'Hospital's rule:

$$\ln(x)=O(\sqrt x)$$

$$\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt x}x$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt x}=0$$

And so we have $\lim x^{1/x}=e^{\ln(x)/x}=e^0=1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1+\frac {1}{y}$ Where $y \rightarrow 0$

Then,

$\lim _{x\to \infty }x^{\frac{1}{x}} =\lim _{y\to 0 }{(1+\frac {1}{y})}^{\frac {y}{1+y}}
= \lim _{y\to 0 }{(1+\frac {1}{y})}^{y\frac {1}{1+y}}$

$=\lim _{y \to 0}{1^{\frac {1}{1+y}}}=1$

Comment: The step from the third line to the last one is, to say the least, very questionable: how could you *justify* to take the limit of **only** a part of the expression in the right extreme of the line one before the last, but to leave other part still with $\;y\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, the step before the last step should be $={1^{\frac {1}{1}}}$

Comment: If $y\to 0$, then $1/y\to\infty$. Then in the end you have: $1+\infty$, which is evidently not $1$.

Comment: $\lim _{y\to 0 }{(1+\frac {1}{y})}^y=1$ @Physicist137 this limit is well known which is equal to 1.

Comment: Oh! Obviously. You are right. My mistake. Sorry... =). And +1. =).

Comment: @Physicist137 Never mind.