# $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^k}{2^n}$ without l'Hopital

Tags: limits

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Let $N>?$. For any integer $n>N$ we have
$$\frac{n^k}{2^n}<\varepsilon.$$
I don't know how to proceed here sensically.

I'd say we have to start with

$$<\frac{n^k}{2^N}$$

But what do we do here about the $n^k$?

Remember, I don't want to use l'Hopital or for me unproven limit laws like "exponents grow faster than powers"

Also, I don't want to use hidden l'Hopital, i.e. argumenting with derivatives. Since we don't even have proven derivative laws.

Comment: Write $n^k$ as $2^{k\log_2 n}$.

Comment: Consider $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, where $a_n = \dfrac{n^k}{2^n}$.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468/201168) (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/)*)

Comment: @Workaholic thanks for the site-tip. Could you mark as duplicate?

Comment: @Null  Done. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the logarithm. One gets

$$\log{n^k\over 2^n}=k\log{n}-n\log{2}=-n\left(\log{2}-k{\log{n}\over n}\right)$$

Now when $n\to\infty$ one has $\log{n}/n\to 0$ and so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log{n^k\over 2^n}=-\infty$$

And so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^k\over 2^n}=0$$

Comment: Can you explain why we can conclude the last one? what is the reverse of taking the logarithm? If we have log$(a)=-\infty$ then we have something like $a^{-\infty}=0$?

Comment: We are just using $\lim_{-\infty}e^x=0$ and the inverse function of the logarithm is the exponential

Comment: but the log is base 2 would that make any difference? and exponential needs ln right?