# Find $\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty}(x^9e^{2x})$ without using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know that $\lim \frac{x^n}{e^x} = 0$ because $e^x$ grows faster than $x^n$.

So, in this case, I think that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty}(x^9e^{2x}) = 0$$ because $e^x$ is going to tend to zero faster than $x^9$ is going to tend to $- \infty$. (does that make sense?)

Is that correct? How do I solve this?

Comment: Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial . There are proofs without L'Hopital,

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = -2x$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty } x^9 e^{2x}=\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}\frac{y^9}{(-2)^9e^y}=\frac{1}{(-2)^9}\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}\frac{y^9}{e^y}=0$$

Comment: that y^9/e^y stuff seems intuitive (and pretty obvious) but how could you PROVE it?

Comment: The OP already knows that from the first sentence isn't it?

Comment: How does $\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty } x^9 e^{2x}=\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}\frac{y^9}{(-2)^9e^y}$ ? What did you do?

Comment: I substitute $y = -2x$ , hence we have  $y^9 = (-2x)^9$ and $2x= -y$. Also as $x \rightarrow - \infty$, $y \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way to solve this:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty}(x^9e^{2x}) = x^9 \cdot \frac{1}{e^{-2x}} = \frac{x^9}{e^{-2x}}$$

And since $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} -2x = \infty$ and $\lim \frac{x^n}{e^x} = 0$, I followed Siong Thye Goh's advice and made $-2x = y$:

$$\frac{x^9}{e^{-2x}} = \frac{(\frac{y}{-2})^9}{e^y} = \frac{1}{(-2)^9} \cdot \frac{y^9}{e^y} = \frac{1}{(-2)^9} \cdot 0  = 0$$

Did I make any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You seem concerned about people relying on the growth property of the exponential function without proving it. I'll give a proof of both, which should hopefully scratch that mental itch.

As a preliminary result, it is possible to derive the exponential power series by elementary means (i.e., excluding derivative methods, Taylor series, l'Hopital's rule, etc), as given, for instance, in [equivalence of exponential definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2).
This shows
$$e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Obviously if $x>0$ then all of the terms of this series are positive, so choosing just one of them must be less than the entire series, that is
$$ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \geq \frac{x^n}{n!},\quad\text{for any $n=1,2,\dotsc$}$$

Now, applying this idea with $n=k+9$,
$$ \frac{x^9}{e^{2x}} \leq \frac{x^9}{(2x)^{k+9}/(k+9)!}
= \frac{(k+9)!}{2^{k+9}} \cdot \frac{1}{x^k}
$$
If $k > 0$, then
$$ 0\leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^9}{e^{2x}} \leq \frac{(k+9)!}{2^{k+9}}\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^k} = 0$$

So for the original problem,
$$ \lim_{x\to-\infty} x^9 e^{2x} 
= \lim_{y = -x \to\infty} (-y)^9 e^{2(-y)}
= - \lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{y^9}{e^{2y}}
= 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the statement $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}dx=n!,\,\lim_{x\to\infty}x^n e^{-x}=0$. If the first half is true for a given $n\ge 0$, the second half is true too as otherwise the integral would diverge. The full statement can therefore be proven by induction, with the second half of the $n=k$ case proving the first half of the $n=k+1$ case by integration by parts.