# $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac {3^n}{n^32^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, fractions

I'm trying to evaluate $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac {3^n}{n^3 \cdot 2^n}$$

Can someone help me?
It should be 0

Comment: No it isn't 0, it's $+\infty$.

Comment: It is $\frac{1.5^n}{n^3}$.

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{n^3}{1.5^n} < \infty$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial)

Comment: Note that $$\frac {3^n}{n^3 \cdot 2^n}=e^{n\log 3-3\log n-n\log 2} \to +\infty$$ indeed $$n\log 3-3\log n-n\log 2=n\left(\log 3-\log 2-3\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\to +\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Prove that $$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n>n^4$$ for all $n\geq40.$

Comment: Yes, I did,$ \frac {3^n}{n^3}>2^n $indeed and the limit should be $\infty$, but the associated series should converge because I tried the ratio test and root test and it converges,

Comment: how could be that the series converges and  the limite diverges?

Comment: The limit is equal to $+\infty$ because for $n\geq40$ we have  $\frac{3^2}{n^32^n}\geq n\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: You are welcome!