# What is the limit of $\frac{n^k}{a^n}$

Tags: limits

What is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^k}{a^n},$$
where $a \in \mathbb{Q}, a>1,k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: if dv, please explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{n^k}}}{{{a^n}}}}  <  + \infty $ by ratio test. So we have 
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{{n^k}}}{{{a^n}}} = 0.$$

Comment: You could mention the "divergence test" to connect the dots.