# Determine if this series converges or diverges. What test to use?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Say I have this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}$$

I think I can compare it to $$b = \frac{3}{2}^n$$ which is a geometric series that diverges.

But where do I go from here? The issue is that the numerator and denominator both increase so I can't say that the original series diverges or not by Comparison Test. What else can I do?

Comment: $n+3^n>n+2^n $.

Comment: Is taht the only way to solve this? I can't use a Comparison Test to prove this?

Comment: You can compare it to $1$ if you like

Comment: @Jwan622, in order for the series to converge to anything it is necessary that the terms converge to 0. But note the terms are always greater than 1.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to use either the comparison test or Limit comparison test like in my book to show this. But what you said makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lord Shark the Unknown commented, since the numerator grows larger quicker than the denominator, we can simply use the divergence test to conclude that the series diverges. 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n} = \infty \neq 0 \Rightarrow \text{diverges}$$

A comparison test is also appropriate. As you noticed, you can compare your sequence to $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$. I would recommend a limit comparison test:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n} \cdot \frac{2^n}{3^n} =\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{3^n}}{\frac{1}{2^n}}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n}{3^n}+1}{\frac{n}{2^n}+1} =1$$
Since $0<1<\infty$, and $\sum\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$ diverges, the original sum has the same behavior and diverges as well.

Comment: How do I formally show taht the limit approaches infinity?

Comment: One way to do that is to multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{2^n}$. Then you get the limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n/2^n + (3/2)^n}{n/2^n+1} $$
Although it's not notationally correct, we could "plug in infinity" and get $\frac{0+\infty}{0+1} = \frac{\infty}{1} = \infty$

Comment: It's an axiom that n/2^n goes to 0 as n -> infinity right? No further proof needed? How did you do the multiplication to get the new limit in the limit comparison test? I think I'm missing a step.

Comment: We wouldn't call it an axiom, but yes, there are theorems that state that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{2^n} = 0$. Most likely, no further work would be necessary. 

As for the LCT, I'm computing $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$, where $a_n = \frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}$ and $b_n = \frac{3^n}{2^n}$.

Comment: How did you get to $$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n}{3^n} + 1}{\frac{n}{2^n} + 1}$$

Comment: I edited my answer. Does that clear up the confusion?

Comment: Regarding $n/2^n \to 0$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial (and its many duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

One of my sayings is that
you don't need to get the best possible
values when finding limits -
good enough is good enough.

In this case
$\frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}
\gt \frac{3^n}{2\cdot 2^n}
=\frac12(\frac32)^n
$
and the sum of these
clearly diverges -
heck, the individual terms
diverge.