# Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove a limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}=0,$$

where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I already tried to pick some interval as $[0,x]$ or $[x,x+a]$ and let $x$ tend to infinity, but without success...

Comment: [Very closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468)

Comment: The OP explictly asks for a proof using the Mean Value Theorem, so I don't think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial/2736744#2736744) uses l'Hopital's rule, which is a consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.