# Inequality: If $\alpha>1$, is $\log^\alpha(x)\leq x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $\alpha>1$. Is $\log^\alpha(x)\leq x$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Relevant question: [(Question 55468)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- the logarithm is an increasing function
- so consider $y=\log(x)$ and
- whether $y^\alpha\leq e^y$ when $y \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
From the power series,
$e^x > x^n/n!$.

Take logs and choose
$n > \alpha+1$.