# Does $n^{1000000}/2^{n}$ converge as $n\rightarrow+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Does $n^{1000000}/2^{n}$ converge as $n\rightarrow+\infty$?

To solve this problem, I am only allowed to use elementary properties of limits. This is what I tried. For $n > 1000000$, one has that
\begin{align*}
\frac{n^{1000000}}{2^{n}} = \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{1000000}\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1000000}
\end{align*}

But then I get stuck. This is not homework. Could someone help me out?

Comment: hava a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial

Comment: A general rule of thumb is that exponential functions "eventually grow faster" than geometric functions.  So the limit is $0$.

Comment: Dear @Maximilian Janisch, thanks for the reference. But I think the given answer is a little bit overkill. The exercise whence I got this problem is at the very beginning of the theory of real-valued sequences.

Comment: @BrickByBrick I see what you are saying but I think that you can find a useful and elementary answer to your question there 

Answer (score 2):

Taking logarithms of the terms gives $100000\ln n-n\ln 2$. This tends to $-\infty$ since $$\frac{\ln n}{n}\rightarrow  0$$ and so the terms are tending to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Think about relative growth rates of something simpler like $n^{10}$ versus $2^{n}$ and work your way up.