# recover $\lim\limits_{n\to -\infty}\frac{a^n}{p(n)}=0$ from $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a^n}{p(n)}=\infty$.

Tags: calculus

I was looking at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/55488/340973) that explains why $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a^n}{p(n)}=\infty$ if $a>1$ and $p(n)$ is a polynomial. Now I was wondering if from this information we could recover that $\lim\limits_{n\to -\infty}\frac{a^n}{p(n)}=0$. So I tried $$\lim\limits_{n\to -\infty}\frac{a^n}{p(n)}=\lim\limits_{n\to -\infty}\frac{(1/a)^{-n}}{q(-n)}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1/a)^{n}}{q(n)}$$ but since $1/a<1$ this doesn't really help. Is there a way to recover this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it helps.

Since $1/a < 1,
(1/a)^n \to 0$.
Since $|q(n)| \to \infty$,
there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized I got confused. What I really wanted to show is $\lim\limits_{t\to 0-}\frac{e^{1/t}}{p(t)}=0$. Sorry about that

Comment: You probably ought to ask another question.