# Why is the limit of $\frac{11^n n^4 + 9^n n^9} {7^{2n} +1}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials, exponential-function

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{11^n n^4 + 9^n n^9} {7^{2n} +1}=0$$

I have used the fact exponentials grow faster than polynomials for this question but was wondering whether there was an algebraic way e.g. with the ratio lemma.

Comment: That is probably simplest. Do observe that $7^2$ outguns both $11$ and $9$.

Comment: $\frac{11^n n^4+9^n n^9}{7^{2n}+1}<2\frac{11^n n^9}{7^{2n}}$

Comment: Use ratio test with PNDas' hint to prove the bigger sequence converges to 0. And hence the smaller sequence also converges to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your expression, $7^{2n}= 49^n$ seems to be the dominant term. We can divide both numerator and denominator by $49^n$:

$$a_n = \frac{n^4 \left(\frac{11}{49} \right)^n + n^9\left(\frac{9}{49} \right)^n }{1 + \left(\frac{1}{49}\right)^n}= \frac{\dfrac{n^4}{\left(\frac{49}{11} \right)^n}+ \dfrac{n^9}{\left(\frac{49}{9} \right)^n}}{1 + \left(\dfrac{1}{49} \right)^n}$$

Since $\left(\left(\frac{1}{49} \right)^n\right)$ is a basic null sequence and by the reciprocal rule, $\left(\left(\frac{49}{11} \right)^n\right), \left(\left(\frac{49}{9} \right)^n\right)$ both tend to infinity which makes $\left(\dfrac{n^4}{\left(\frac{49}{11}\right)^n}\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac{n^9}{\left(\frac{49}{9}\right)^n}\right)$ both basic null sequences.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =  \frac{0 + 0}{1 + 0} = 0$$

Alternatively, you can also say that $\left(n^4\left(\frac{11}{49} \right)^n\right)$ and  $\left(n^9\left(\frac{9}{49} \right)^n\right)$ are basic null sequences.

Comment: This argument is wrong. The terms in the numerator are indeterminate forms $\infty\cdot0$ and you cannot conclude so expeditiously. And if you wanted to justify, you would probably invoke "exponentials grow faster than polynomials". So no progress on the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out-complete oversight!

Comment: You can adjust your previous answer in this way $$a_n =  \frac{n^4\left(\frac{11}{49}\right)^n + n^9\left(\frac{9}{49}\right)^n}{1 + \left(\frac{1}{49}\right)^n}=\frac{\frac{n^4}{\left(\frac{49}{11}\right)^n} + \frac{n^9}{\left(\frac{49}{9}\right)^n}}{1 + \left(\frac{1}{49}\right)^n}=\ldots$$

Comment: @user, thanks for the helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

According to the suggestion by Jyrki we have

$$\frac{11^n n^4 + 9^n n^9} {7^{2n} +1} \le \frac{11^n n^9 + 11^n n^9} {7^{2n} }=2\cdot\frac{ 11^n n^9} {49^n }=2\cdot\frac{ n^9} {\left(\frac{49}{11}\right)^n }\le 2 \cdot \frac{n^9}{4^n}$$

Refer also to the related

- [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468/505767)

Comment: so then do you use the fact that 4^n will grow at a rate much greater than n^9?

Comment: @Emily.KH Yes you can take this a general fact which can be proved in many ways, ratio test works or as an laternative by induction, depending on what are you given to know and allowed to use. I add some reference for that.

Answer (score 0):

Do some basic asymptotic analysis:

It is easy to check that $9^nn^9=o\bigl(11^nn^4\bigr)$, so the numerator is asymptotically equivalent to $11^nn^4$ and
$$\frac{9^nn^9+11^nn^4}{7^{2n}+1}\sim_\infty\frac{11^nn^4}{7^{2n}}=\Bigl(\frac{11}{49}\Bigr)^n n^4\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence

$$s_n:=\frac{n^k}{a^n}$$ where $a>1$.

We have

$$\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}=\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^k\frac1a.$$

Now if we take

$$n>\frac1{\sqrt[k]a-1},$$ we have $$\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}<\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^k\frac1a=r<1$$ and by induction

$$s_{n+m}<s_nr^m\to0.$$

This proves that any exponential grows faster than any power and it is not big deal to generalize to any polynomial.

---

E.g. with

$$\frac{n^9}{7^{2n}},$$ as of $n\ge2$ the sequence is dominated by a geometric series of common ratio $\dfrac{19683}{25088}.$