# What is a slower decay rate than hyperbolic?

Tags: exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

Hyperbolic decay

$$f_\alpha(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha x + 1}
$$

is slower than exponential decay

$$f(x) = e^{-x}$$

where $\alpha > 0$ is a scaling factor. The larger that $\alpha$ is, the steeper the descent towards $0$.

[image: Plot of hyperbolic and vs. exponential decay]

What would be a slower decay function than hyperbolic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any reciprocal of a function that grows slower than linear. E. g. a much slower decay rate than hyperbolic would be $$\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$$ or even $$\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(x))}$$

Comment: are there names for those? log-hyperbolic?

Comment: Probably just logarithmic decay

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}.$$

Reciprical square root,

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$

or $x^{-p}$ for any $0<p<1$:

$$h_p(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}.
$$

These are much slower than $\frac{1}{x}$ as $x \to \infty$, since

$\large{\frac{f(x)}{h_p(x)} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^p}} = \frac{x^p}{x} =}$ $x^{p-1}\to 0 $ as $ x \to \infty\ $ because $p-1<0. $

Comment: how do these compare to logarithmic decay?

Comment: @develarist since the logarithm grows way slower than any positive power of x, logarithmic decay would be slower

Comment: logarithmic decay is always a lot slower than $h_p(x).$ For example, $ \frac{1}{\log_{10} (1,000,000)} = \frac16,\ $ whereas $\frac{1}{1,000,000^{\frac13}} = \frac{1}{100}.$

Comment: See here for a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial

Comment: @AdamRubinson, do these $h_p(x)$ functions have a commonly used name? I'm looking for something in the vein of "exponential decay", but clearly not exponential.

Comment: @DavidTarandek I don't know, but I can't think of a name off the top of my head. But like I say, I don't know.