# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{1296}}{6^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, standard-deviation

I need to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{1296}}{6^n}$$ I have nothing yet, maybe sandwich theorem but I'm not sure.
Thanks in advance  for help.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468/42969.

Comment: L'Hopitale rule 1296 times?

Comment: The example was helpful tank you

Comment: @ShirMoshe More like this : create the statement $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^k}{6^n} = 0$ for all integers $k$, to prove by mathematical induction. Prove the base case, and then use L'Hopital for the inductive case. This means you don't need to do L'Hopital 1296 times.

Comment: FWIW, $n^{1296}=6^n$ at $n\approx 1.0013854 \text{ & } 6331.3374$

Comment: @ShirMoshe If you are not willing to try what other suggests, what the point of posting the question? A-Level Student's answer solves the problem in that way.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on this limit problem here. Posting questions which are just problem statements is discouraged here.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, there is an alternative way, by taking the power of 1296 out common from the whole brakett........then apply l's hopital only once (as I cannot post it as an answer, hence this comment)

Answer (score 3):

Let $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{1296}}{6^n}$$
Applying L' Hopital's rule once, we see that
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1296n^{1295}}{6^n\ln6}$$
We can keep on applying L' Hopital's rule (as we always will have a indeterminate form), until we get
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1296!~n}{6^n(\ln6)^{1295}}$$
Applying this once more we are left with
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1296!}{6^n(\ln6)^{1296}}=0$$
So we see that $L=0$.
I hope that was helpful. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)