# Does the rule " divide by highest denominator power" apply outside the field of rational functions? ( Context : limits and asymptotes)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, analysis, asymptotics

Note : I assume here that the function $f(x)$ as defined below is not a rational function ( i.e. a quotient of polynomials).

---

I found this question in a " maturité" test  ( Swiss high school final exam), dating from $2014$ :

Let $\LARGE f $ be a function defined by :  $\LARGE f(x)= \frac {x^2 - e^{x+1}} {x^2 +e^x}$ . Justfy that $\mathbb R$ is the domain of $\LARGE f$ and determine the asymptotes of function $\LARGE f$.

In order to find a possible horizontal asymptote, I asked Symbolab :

$\LARGE lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \bigg(\frac {x^2 - e^{x+1}} {x^2 +e^x}\bigg)$.

I observe that, in order to tackle this problem, Symbolab applies a rule that , according to what I thought , only held for rational functions, namely the rule :

" divide by the highest denominator power",

whch yields ( with $\LARGE e^x$ playing the role of " highest denominator power ") :

> $\LARGE \frac {\frac {x^2}{e^x} - e^1} {\frac {x^2}{e^x}+ 1}$

I have two questions :

(1) does the rule " divide by highest denominator power" actually ***apply outside the field  of rational functions*** ( i.e. quotients of polynomials)?

(2) since $x$ is a variable that may ( apparently)  take values less that two, ***what justfies the fact of identifying the " highest denominator power " to the second term, namely $\LARGE e^x$*** and not to $\LARGE x^2$?

Exam :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To answer your first question, we want to divide by the largest term in the denominator (as a generalization of the highest denominator power rule for rational functions).

Since $x\rightarrow\infty$, we want to divide by the largest quantity then, and in that case, it is indeed the exponential term.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial) explains why the exponential function grows faster than *any* polynomial function, given sufficiently large values of $x$.

2. Your second question does not seem relevant for this question since we want $x\rightarrow\infty$, not $x$ near 2.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what is being done is not “divide by the highest denominator power”; it is “divide by the thing that grows faster”. In this case, that thing is $e^x$ ($e^{x+1}$ is another possibility, since it grows at the same rate as $e^x$). And, yes, it's a good approach.