# arrange functions in increasing order of growth rate

Tags: algorithms

Arrange the following functions in increasing order of growth rate:
$n^2$,$(5/4)^n$,
$logn*logn$,
$log(n!)$

I think this is the order but I have problem with proving it:
$logn*logn<log(n!)<(5/4)^n<n^2$

I would like to see if my arrangement is correct or not and how to prove it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What is your problem in proving it?

Comment: @jimjim I don't understand how to compare longn! and (5/4)^n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrangement is not correct. Also, using inequalities are not the best way to represent growth - you could do it with big-O-notation, but I'll rather write it out.

$\log n\cdot \log n$ is slower than $\log(n!)$, slower than $n^2$ slower than $(5/4)^n$.

To prove it, it is sufficient to prove inequalities on their *differential quotients*. Thus, we think of all the functions as functions on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$, so let's replace $n$ by $x$, and we want to prove

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)^2 \leq \frac{d}{dx}\log(\Gamma(x+1)) \leq \frac{d}{dx}x^2 \leq \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac54\right)^x ,$$

holding for all $x\geq N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Notice that I replaced $x!$ by $\Gamma(x+1)$, the Gamma function on $x+1$. This is necessary to extend the factorial function to the reals - it holds that $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so it's just a continuation.

Using usual differentiation rules, we get

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)^2 = 2\frac{\log(x)}{x} ,\qquad \frac{d}{dx}\log(\Gamma(x+1))=\frac{\Gamma'(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)} ,\\ \frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x, \qquad \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac54\right)^x =\log(5/4)\left(\frac54\right)^x.$$

Now, $\frac{\Gamma'(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)} = \psi(x+1)$ is the digamma function, and it is known that $\psi(x+1)\sim \log(x)-\frac{1}{2x}$. Also, it is clear that $2\frac{\log(x)}{x}$ goes to zero for $x\to\infty$. Hence the first inequality should be clear, and I hope you are familiar with $\log(x)\leq x$ for $x\geq 1$, giving you the second inequality. For the final one, note that $\log(5/4)\left(\frac54\right)^{30}\approx 180$, while $2\cdot 30=60$, and the exponential functions grows with a *factor of* $5/4$ every time you increase $x$ by $1$, while the linear functions only grows by adding $2$.

This is of course not a completely formal proof of the final inequality, but the fact that exponential functions grows faster than polynomial functions is a fundamental fact, see [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial) for a rigourous proof.

Comment: You don't need to appeal to anything as involved as the derivative of $\Gamma$ here; you need only the elementary theorem that exponentials dominate polynomials (which therefore dominate logarithms), $\displaystyle \lim \frac{n^a}{b^n}=0$, and some basic applications of the power/logarithm laws, including $\log (ab)=\log a+\log b$.

Comment: @Jam Sure, there are very likely simpler ways of solving this, this was just what came to mind. Feel free to add another answer.