# $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{x} - x^{k} = + \infty , \forall k \geq 1 $?

Tags: limits

I was wondering if this was true. My logic was:

1. At x=0, $e^{x}$ is always greater than $x^{k}$, for $k \geq 1$.
2. The kth derivative of $e^{x}$ is $e^{x}$.
3. The kth derivative of $x^{k}$ is 1.
4. For $x \geq 1$, the kth derivative of $e^{x}$ will be greater than the kth derivative of $x^{k}$.
5. Therefore, the (k-1)th derivative of $e^{x}$ will eventually be greater than the (k-1)th derivative of $x^{k}$.
6. Thus, the same logic applies to the (k-2)th derivative of $e^{x}$ eventually being greater than the (k-2)th derivative of $x^{k}$.
7. This pattern goes on until the 1st derivative of $e^{x}$ is greater than the 1st derivative of $x^{k}$, meaning that $e^{x}$ will eventually surpass $x^{k}$, proving that the limit holds.

Is my reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simpler: $e^x > \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: By $e^{x} - x^{k}=e^x\left(1-\frac{x^k}{e^x}\right)$ and $\frac{x^k}{e^x} \to 0$ or by the definition of $e^x$ or also by l'Hospital for example.

Comment: Related [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial)